# VirtualBox (Linux Host): can I protect system USB keyboard and mouse from accidentally assigning to a VM via USB filter?

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox on a Linux host. As it is for private use only, I've also installed the VirtualBox Extension Pack.

Sometimes, I need to use a USB device inside a VM via passthrough USB filters. When opening the USB settings to add a new filter, the dialog offers me **all** USB devices, including mouse and keyboard used on the host. When I assign one of them to the VM, it stops working on the host until the VM is stoeed. So I need to be very careful.

To prevent accidents like this, I'd like to tell VirtualBox to never offer these devices for USB filters. This should affect the USB menu at the bottom of the VM window as well as the devices offered in the settings dialog.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: In Virtual Box, you can select the USB device. It should be easy to avoid your USB mouse and keyboard.   https://www.groovypost.com/howto/mount-usb-drive-virtualbox/

Comment: Even if you did simply shutting down the VM would return the device to the host machine.  I would imagine using the escape key sequence would also do that.

Comment: @John easy to avoid ... well ... it depends. accidents can always happen and my question is about how to avoid them.

Comment: @Ramhound sure ... shutting down will return the devices. but what if something is running in the VM that would ruin the VM if interrupted ? Or the VM is in a state where it does not accept input at all ? e.g. a Windows 10 VM saying "updates are being installed. do not power off the computer"

Comment: I do understand but I do not see any way to change the selection criteria. I will continue to look around.